# I've installed libcurl 7.51, but autogen could not recognize it

Tags: curl, libcurl, configure, autogen, cgminer

I'm trying to install cgminer. using the instructions:

```
# git clone https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer
# cd cgminer && git checkout v3.1.1
# cd ADL_SDK && wget http://www.lurkmore.com/mining/ADL_SDK.zip && unzip -j ADL_SDK.zip 'include/adl_*.h'
# cd .. && ./autogen.sh && ./configure --enable-opencl --enable-scrypt && make && make install
# cd && rm -rf cgminer && mkdir .cgminer
```

But, the autogen.sh show the following error:

```
checking for LIBCURL... no
checking for LIBCURL... no
configure: error: Missing required libcurl dev >= 7.18.2
```

So, I downloaded the last source code from [Curl website](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Linux)

And checking the version:

```
$ curl-config --version
libcurl 7.51.0
```

But running the ./autogen.sh again I got the same error:

```
checking for LIBCURL... no
checking for LIBCURL... no
configure: error: Missing required libcurl dev >= 7.18.2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
configure: error: Missing required libcurl dev >= 7.18.2
```

indicates that you need the curl development files. Depending on your system they can be installed via

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

for Debian and Debian-based distributions like Ubuntu.
(Alternative packages are `libcurl4-nss-dev` for the NSS flavour of curl or `libcurl4-openssl-dev` for the OpenSSL flavour of curl.)

On RPM-based distributions like CentOS, use

```
sudo yum install libcurl-devel
```

instead. Package names and package managers might vary, depending on what Linux distribution you are using.

Unless you depend on a very recent version of curl, it should be sufficient to use the packages that are provided by your distribution instead of downloading the most recent version from the curl website. It saves you the trouble of compiling the library yourself, and the distributions also make sure that the library and its development files are placed in a location where configure scripts should find them.

Answer (score 0):

look for lib path at debian packages website at files section and run before configure

```sh
export LIBCURL_LIBS=-L/path/to/libfile
export LIBCURL_CFLAGS=-I/path/to/include/dir
```